# Schedule jobs without access to SM36 in SAP

Tags: jobs, sap-basis

Is there any way to schedule SAP Jobs without having access to the `SM36` transaction?

I have the "Run in background" option but what I want is to have the file saved somewhere or sent by email or something like that.

Can I do this without access to `SM36`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule and run jobs programatically using following function modules `JOB_OPEN` and `JOB_CLOSE`. Google for those names and you will surely find some good examples.